# How to do painting in cocos2d android?

Tags: cocos2d-android

I want to do painting on screen as we can do in native android. Here is the example code which is in API demos. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html
I want to do same in layer. I should also be able to erase  the paint color.
Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.